# PHP: best options to process csv files with a queue mechanism in order to make massive inserts on mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, csv, queue

looking for some general advice on how to go about this. I have the following task(s) planned:

**The following is already working:**.
User submits a CSV file via the form on my site.
The file/url of the file gets sent to a different server for processing (loop through each csv row, connect to my WordPress site and create each item as a product via the WooCommerce REST API).

**What I want to achieve:**.
If for example, 5 people submit a CSV at roughly the same time that’s a lot of writing to the database at once (some of the files could have 500, 1000+ rows). I would prefer to do a ‘queue’ system:

- 1 CSV file received.
- Process the file, do all the product creation etc.
- When finished, move to the next CSV and process that one next.

**Note:** When I say the CSV is received, I am simply passing the csv url and doing a file_get_contents in the script which processes it.

Comment: Keep in mind that you also need to handle cases when received CSV file could not be processed due to some constraints (for example, a record already existing in the database), and you need to either reject it entirely, or process what you can, but give user feedback about troubling records.

Answer (score 1):

First point: you have an high workload to process, that it's not depending by the quantity of files only, but also from a single file length.
Eg. you have a csv with 1000+ lines.

That kind of file would lock your queue for a long amount of time and consume a lot of the mysql reserved memory.

So I will move like follows:

1. Take any file and translate them into a series of mysql [multiple insert](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html) query.
   In this way you reduce the number of roundtrips from mysql to application that would happen instead if you do separate inserts.
   Consider that the best way is to split any file in bulk insert scripts of 200 circa records to avoid high mysql memory consumption, that would slow down the process.
2. Create a queue job for any bulk import script you create and send them to your queue processor, I would avoid to use a cron job and move for an ampq implementation using this wrapper library: [php-amqlib](https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib) as starting point.
3. Do not use file_get_contents but [fgetcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php), since loading all the file at once and process manually could be not the best option.